# kinect or monocular camera?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,should i use kinect to do a semantic map ? can i use just monocular camera  ?
what all benefits to use a kinect in roboearth robots that can't done using normal camera ?

and if i want to navigate my robot within a room to reach the table , and begin to infer what is missing components in this table

to do this i must upload object maps of the all table components to Roboearth server
using ( kinect or camera ?? )
and this semantic mapping(must be kinect or can use camera) ??
and begin to  matching a picture of object with these models in the Database so it takes a pictures when reaching the table ?

all these using of camera in the project make me Confused

thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46238/kinect-or-monocular-camera-??/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1-Kinect camera can do semantic mapping

2- this video explan how robot infer for missing components
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igtgkznwE6I&feature=share

---

Originally posted by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) with karma: 238 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-18**:
and this one explain how semantic mapping using kinect
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHju7IH8nck

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see this question about semantic mapping:

http://answers.ros.org/question/45757/semantic-mapping/

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1